# Short story about a man who steals another man's boat but can't find drinkable water

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

I'm trying to find a story that I heard about 20 years ago. It involves a man who is at sea and crosses paths with a well-stocked boat, so he kills the captain and claims it for himself. Although there is plenty of food on board, he can't seem to find any drinkable water. Desperate, he eventually drinks sea water, becomes ill, and falls overboard. As he is about to drown, he notices the word "water" printed on the bottom of a tank attached to the boat.

Additional info I forgot to mention when I submitted this question:

- I believe the protagonist's name was "Krueger" or something that sounds like it
- The teacher who read the story to me was a fan of Saki and frequently read to us short stories by him, but it's not clear whether this particular one is by him.